# Azure AD : AADSTS50003: No signing key is configured

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I configured azure AD as an identity provider for my organization's application

as specified in the below blog

[Bring your own app with Azure AD Self-Service SAML configuration](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2015/06/17/bring-your-own-app-with-azure-ad-self-service-saml-configuration-gt-now-in-preview.aspx)

I created an application under activity directory and configured single signon (SAML2) for the same as below

```
SIGN ON URL
https://abc.xxxx.com/myapp/saml/ssoRequest?ticket=kcflmlmnpgg

ISSUER URL
https://abc.xxxx.com

REPLY URL

https://abc.xxxx.com/myapp/ssoResponse
```

whenever i try to access the application its redirecting the request to azure login. But I am getting a bad request error and its showing the below message

```
AADSTS50003: No signing key is configured.
```

Whenever I try to access my application, it is redirecting me to azure login page. It asks me to login , if I am not already logged in and after login the above error is thrown. If I am already logged in; the error is shown directly

Am I missing something in the configuration

Comment: Can you specify how you configured it- what libraries did you use, what parameters you are passing

Comment: A CorrelationId and timstamp would also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have updated the question. @Rich Randall i am sorry I dont have it right now with me. I will post it tomorrow. If it is of any help, for every request I get a different CorrelationId . I will really appreciate it , if you can help me understand how correlation ID is important in this context.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The request was not signed. After sigining the request it started working.

Comment: Does anyone have a a clue about how to fix this issue if the service provider cannot provide a signed request ?

Comment: @Freaky Thommi - how do you obtain the public key from AzureAD to sign your app's authentication requests?